# How is a unit test written for a method in this class?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

How is a unit test written for a method like derov in this example class? I would like to have an example of how to write a test case in code to test if a string input with only big letters would give the result as I expect.

Edit: I have solved this myself by writing a test case like the one posted above the class below.

```
   ///If the expected result and the res variable is equal then the test case has not detected a   fault.
   [TestCase]
    public void TestStringWithOnlyBigConsonantsDerov()
    {
  //declare a string res = classname.methodname("string"); 
        string res = rovar.derov("BOBCOCFOFGOGHOHJOJKOKLOL")
  //check if equal ("expected result", variable holding real result)
        Assert.AreEqual("BCFGHJKL", res); 
    }

class CodeToTest
{
    static class danish
    {
        static string lower_consonants = "bcdghjklmnpqrstvwxz";
        static string upper_consonants = "BCFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ";

        /// <summary>
        /// Encode the string to danish.
        /// Normal is a parameter that contains text which a user types in and 
        /// which shall be translated into danish. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="normal">Normal string.</param>
        /// <returns>Encoded string.</returns>
        public static string danish(string normal)
        {
            if (normal == null) 
                return null;

            System.Text.StringBuilder builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            foreach (char c in normal)

                if (lower_consonants.Contains(c.ToString()))
                    builder.Append(c + "o" + c);


                else if (upper_consonants.Contains(c.ToString())) 
                    builder.Append(c + "O" + c);

                else
                    builder.Append(c);

            return builder.ToString();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Decode a string from danish.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dan">Encoded string.</param>
        /// <returns>Normal string.</returns>
        public static string derov(string dan)
        {
            if (dan == null)
                return null;

            foreach (char c in lower_consonants)
                dan = dan.Replace(c + "o" + c, c.ToString());

            foreach (char c in upper_consonants)
                dan = dan.Replace(c + "O" + c, c.ToString());

            return dan;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to SO. Writing unit tests in any language doesn't require to reinvent the wheel. There are many unit testing frameworks, which you can use for this purpose. One of them, that I have used, is the NUnit, http://www.nunit.org/. Furthermore, there is a tutorial in this site that you could follow. Doing so, you will be in a very short amount of time capable of defining what you are going to test and writing the corresponding unit test.

Comment: There's no real "start" and "end". Simply find what are all the code paths, and test them all. The easiest way however would be to write the tests before (Look up `TDD`) and only write the minimum production code to make the tests work. That way, you have virtually 100% unit test coverage.

Comment: I have edited the question, could anyone have a look at it and let me know how I managed. Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding, the class has no internal state; both strings could as well be `const` since they are never written to after initialization. Both functions `danish` and `derov` could be tested by defining a list of arguments with their desired outputs and comparing them argument-wise to the actual results. Furthermore, as this is C#, Visual Studio has an integrated test framework. Test projects can also be evaluated from the command line, which is useful for automated testing.